# Image displayed when app used locally but not working after deployment to Shinyapp.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to get an image to display in my shiny app based on a user selection by clicking points on a map that display the photos’ location. The app works fine and displays the photo when I use the app locally via Rstudio but the photo does not display when I deploy the app to shinyapp.io. I believe the problem is that the fpath is not annotated correctly to reach the image but I am not sure what the path should read to reach the image when deployed to shinyapp.io.

I have tried a number of solutions including:

- As per think link, I saved copies of the images to both the base folder that holds the app file and the www folder thinking that shiny might automatically look in the www folder since that is where images are normally sourced for displaying in the app but that did not work as paste0(dat$PhotoID,".jpg") or paste0(“www”,dat$PhotoID,".jpg") or paste0(“/www”,dat$PhotoID,".jpg") or paste0(“/www/”,dat$PhotoID,".jpg"). When I run the app locally I can access the image using paste0("./",dat$PhotoID,".jpg") or paste0(dat$PhotoID,".jpg")
- I tried to link to a “resource folder” but could not find a function for this call nor do I have an Rmd file as per this link.
- This link looked useful but altering if a backslash occurred above did not affect the outcome. I also am unfamiliar with relative vs absolute file paths although for apps deployed on shinyapp.io I would expect relative file paths would be the most appropriate.
- I have previously used a static image in my app accessed using img(src = "FigureCombo.png") but since I am using an imageOutput() I don’t think that is appropriate.

Does anyone have any advice on how to access stored images when app is deployed to shinyapp.io?

Thanks

Here is the relevant code:

`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
mainPanel(
imageOutput("myImage", height = "200px"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$myImage <- renderImage({
    photo <- selected_photo()
    if(is.null(photo)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      list(src = photo,
           contentType = 'image/jpg',
           width = 300,
           height = 400,
           style = 'border-style: solid; border-color: red;',
           alt = "No point selected yet or that point does not have an image...")
    }
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
 selected_photo <- reactive({
    dat <- reactive_data()    
    photoid <- input$wsmap_marker_click$id
    dat <- dat[dat$PhotoID %in% photoid,]
     fpath <- paste0(dat$PhotoID,".jpg")      # works when local but not shinyapp.io 
    return(fpath)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of the directory structure on an unfamiliar host, you might list the subdirectories of the work directory (as seen by server.R) and log it to your user interface like so:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
## ...
verbatimTextOutput('log')
## ...
)

server <- function(input, output) {
## ...
output$log <- renderPrint(list.dirs(getwd()))
## ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me started to see the file directory pathways and to identify how I could call direct and indirect pathways to my folders/files.

Comment: My pleasure. Note that there's a dedicated function `file.exists` to check for a file's, well, existence :-)